# Why is this python if statement not equal to true?

Tags: python, logic, statements

I was going over an assignment, and came across something that confused me, as am I not crazy good with python.  Here is the code.

```
def main():


    list = [1,2]
    x = 2

    if (x in list == True):
       print("hi")

    if (x in list):
       print("Why does this proc?")

main()
```

I believed the output would be both, but the output is only the second if statement.  I know that in C, if you had something like

```
if (x = 6)
```

That since there is only one '=' that x is now equal to 6. (As its read, if (), x = 6).

Is something similar happening to this python code?  Is it checking 'list == true' first, then from there checking about x being in list?

Any insight would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: That's exactly it. It's checking if `x in list and list == True`.

Comment: Out of curiosity, why am I not getting an error? I also did some testing and tried `if (list == False)` and that is also not happening.  When python compares the two, what is the outcome?

Comment: Why would you get an error? That's a perfectly legal Python statement. And yeah, that's not going to work either, `list` is not equal to `False`.

Comment: In this case I'd say the behaviour is a bit quirky, but it is what brings us things like `4 < x < 8`.

Comment: So when I actually do `if (list == False)` what is python looking at?  How is it comparing the list and the boolean to know its neither true or false? Is it comparing the list as a variable or the contents of the list?

Comment: list is evaluated to False when len(list) == 0, otherwise it's True

Comment: so if `list = [1,2]`. and then i tried `if (list == True)`, that would 'proc'?

Comment: `bool([1,2])` is True and `bool([])` is False. However `[1,2] == True` is False. So `if list` would 'proc', but `if list == True` would not.

Comment: Mmm very strange, to me that is not intuitive at all.  Thank you for the information!

Comment: You could check out [how objects are evaluated for boolean values](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#object.__nonzero__). That's why `if list:` would proc. However comparing list and boolean value is False, since they are not even the same type.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As you can see, yes, your expression requires explicit grouping:

```
>>> 2 in [1,2] == True
False
>>> (2 in [1,2]) == True
True
```

Note that, as @tavo and @MorganThrapp mention, the version without parentheses is doing a chained comparison, checking that `2 in [1,2]` and then checking that `[1,2] == True`. The latter is false, so the full expression is also false.

By the way, don't name your variables after built-ins like `list`, or you won't be able to use those functions easily.

Also, you don't have to compare the result of an expression to `True`:

```
>>> 2 in [1,2]
True
```

Doing so is the equivalent of asking "is 'the cake is ready' a true statement?" as opposed to "is the cake ready?".

Comment: Are you sure it's just about operation priority? Because `2 in ([1, 2] == True)` throws an error.

Comment: My apologies about the terminology, it was just something I whipped up to post on here, it wasn't code actually being used.  Thank you for the information!

Comment: @tavo, `[1,2] == True` is a bool, and `2 in ([1, 2] == True)` is equivalent to `2 in False`, hence the TypeError: argument of type 'bool' is not iterable.

Comment: @Neapolitan, I do get that, I just thought that original version of this answer was a bit misleading (at least how I understood it) saying that you get False because python internaly does `2 in ([1,2] == True)` instead of `(2 in [1,2]) == True`. Current version of answer seems correct and deserves upvote ;)